# Hybris how to prevent generation of addonsrc and commonwebsrc during compilation?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

We have a structure where we have 2 modulegen extensions testfacades and teststorefront. We have also generated testwebservices extension from ycommercewebservices. We have installed orderselfserviceaddon to teststorefront.

Now when we are adding testfacades dependency to testwebservices, we are getting compile error below:

```
  [echo] Compile addonsrc testwebservices - orderselfserviceaddon
[yjavac] Compiling 7 source files to C:\carrefour\HybrisFood\hybris\bin\custom\carrefour\testwebservices\web\webroot\WEB-INF\classes
[yjavac] ----------
[yjavac] 1. ERROR in C:\carrefour\HybrisFood\hybris\bin\custom\carrefour\testwebservices\web\addonsrc\orderselfserviceaddon\de\hybris\platform\orderselfserviceaddon\controllers\pages\AccountReturnsPageController.java (at line 16)
[yjavac]     import de.hybris.platform.acceleratorstorefrontcommons.annotations.RequireHardLogIn;
[yjavac]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[yjavac] The import de.hybris.platform.acceleratorstorefrontcommons.annotations cannot be resolved
```

Why its happening? How can I prevent this folders to generate during build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you installed orderselfserviceaddon onto your testwebservices project, it copies over all source code (inside of the web folder) of that addon into the addonsrc folder. This is how the addon install process of hybris works. With every `ant clean all` this folder will be overwritten.

It appears that the addon you installed (orderselfserviceaddon) had a dependency on an annotation in another addon.

- If you don't need this addon in the test project, remove the `<requires-extension="orderselfserviceaddon"/>` from the **extensioninfo.xml** of the testwebservices addon.
- If you need this code here, you can simply add the required extensions tag in your **extensionsinfo.xml** (of testwebservices) to also include the acceleratorstorefrontcommons code in this addon.

`<requires-extension name="acceleratorstorefrontcommons"/>`

Comment: I have also removed all the XML within buildcallback.xml from testwebservices where I saw that this folder is being regenerated